# Hosted Payment Page and http response

Tags: global-payments-api

We are investigating and issue where the payment action is successful but we haven't received a response from Global payments. We believe this is the root cause. We are obviously keen to confirm this. Does global payments track the responses sent back to the customer. If so if we specified a specific date and time is it possible to get logs?

On separate thread how can we determine when the submit button has been clicked when we are using a Hosted Payment Page.

We made a payment to global payments which went through but the subsequent actions that depended on the response from global payment didn't fire.

Answer (score 0):

These things are usually just a misconfiguration in the response URL of the HPP. Please contact us directly at developers@globalpay.com and we will be able to discuss more specifics about your implementation which may not be suitable for more public forums.

Thanks